# How to check if a pdf is print-protected using pdfbox

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I want to check if a PDF is print-protected using PDFBox Java API. Is there any API to do this or any other way of achieving this?

Awaiting your kind responses.

Arin...

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Like looking up printing permissions in the PDF specification and trying to put that into code?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882581/pdfbox-not-recognising-pdf-to-be-non-printable/19895252#19895252) should give a hint.